# prove that $(\mathbb{R},d_1)$ is a metric space isometric to $(\mathbb{R},d)$

Tags: general-topology

If $d_1$ is defined by $d_1(x,y)=a.d(x,y)$, for ll $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, then show that $(\mathbb{R},d_1)$ is a metric space isometric to $(\mathbb{R},d)$.

I am self studying topology. I don't know how am i going to prove that $d(x_1,x_2)=d_1(f(x_1),f(x_2))$.

This is how i work out:
$d_1(f(x_1),f(x_2))=a.d(f(x_1),f(x_2))$
and I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming $a>0$, otherwise this doesn't make sense.

You need to furnish the isometry. Since distances are getting expanding, just inflate the universe accordingly.

Let $f: (\mathbb{R},d_1) \to (\mathbb{R},d)$ be defined by $f(x)=ax$. It is clearly bijective.

Note that 
$$d(f(x),f(y))=\vert ax-ay\vert=a \vert x-y\vert=a \cdot d(x,y)=d_1(x,y).$$